# Кнопки назад и вперед в history api

Tags: javascript, html5-history-api

Не правильно работают кнопки назад и вперед
Вот код навигации

```
$(document).on("click",'a',function(e){
    url = $(this).attr('href');
    go(url);
    e.preventDefault();
});

addEventListener("popstate",function(e){
    go(location.pathname+location.search);
},false);

function go(url){
    alert(url)
    if(url==='/'){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/',
            type: 'GET',
            beforeSend: function(){

            },
            success: function(data){
                $('article').html(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('error')
            }
        });
    }else if(url.search(/^\/\?a=[\w-\(\)]+$/)===0){
        var link = url.slice(2);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/',
            type: 'GET',
            data: link,
            beforeSend: function(){

            },
            success: function(data){
                $('article').html(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('error')
            }
        });
    }
    history.pushState({url: url}, null, url); 
}
```

Но перейти кнопкой назад можно только 1 раз.
И кнопка Вперед не доступна.
Как исправить?

Comment: мне кажется pushState не надо делать, когда go срабатывает из события popstate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исключите pushState по событиям history API , например так:

```
$(document).on("click",'a',function(e){
    url = $(this).attr('href');
    go(url,1); //здесь
    e.preventDefault();
});

addEventListener("popstate",function(e){
    go(location.pathname+location.search);
},false);

function go(url,pushState){ //здесь
    alert(url)
    if(url==='/'){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/',
            type: 'GET',
            beforeSend: function(){

            },
            success: function(data){
                $('article').html(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('error')
            }
        });
    }else if(url.search(/^\/\?a=[\w-\(\)]+$/)===0){
        var link = url.slice(2);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/',
            type: 'GET',
            data: link,
            beforeSend: function(){

            },
            success: function(data){
                $('article').html(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('error')
            }
        });
    }
   pushState && history.pushState({url: url}, null, url); //здесь
}
```